# _block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse) because of delete command

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, runtime-error, placement-new

```
ifstream ifile("Library.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);

Book *book_obj=new Book; //Book is the class name
if(ifile)
 {
    while(ifile.read((char*)book_obj,sizeof(Book)))
     book_obj->Display_BookDetails();
}
ifile.close();

delete book_obj; //Runtime Error is coming here.If I comment out this, then it works fine
```

I am reading content from a file named Library.dat. When I execute above code I get runtime error Access violation reading location 0x004B9B44. Commenting out delete book_obj works perfectly fine. How shall I delete book_obj to stop memory leakage.

Comment: Show us the class `Book` please. Does it contain any non-POD data members?

Comment: class Book
{
 private:
  string book_Number;
  string book_Name;
  string book_Author;
  string book_Publisher;
  string book_Edition;
  int book_Quantity;
 public:
  Book();
  Book(string,string,string,string,string,int);
};

Answer (score 0):

Your class contains non-POD members. You can't read the structure as a block of bytes without running into problems. You'll have to serialize on your own by creating your own `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Book&)` function:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Book& b)
{
    // extract individually into b's data members
}
```

Now you can do:

```
while (ifile >> book_obj)
{
    book_obj->Display_BookDetails();
}
```